# Custom ArrayAdapter shows duplicate images after scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new to android and by using ArrayAdapter, I am trying to create a listView with title and image. I am getting the images from sqlite databae.(I know, it is not recommended), but so far I am able to create the desired listView.

There are some items in listView, which do not have image and some have images, the problem I am having is when I scroll up and down then my image gets duplicated. The ones that do not have image gets the random image from the list.

I have searched the web and found related threads, but that didn't fix my problem.

My ArrayAdapter code:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataItems> 
{
  Context context;
  LayoutInflater mInflater;

  public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<DataItems> items) 
  {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  /* private view holder class */
  private class ViewHolder 
  {
     ImageView thumdnail;           
     TextView txtTitle;
  } 

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    DataItems rowItem = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) 
    {
      holder = new ViewHolder();

      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null, false);

      holder.thumdnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail2); 
      holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mytitle2);

      convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

    if(rowItem.getThumbnailImageId() != null)
    {
      // here getImage() is converting byte array to bitmap

      Bitmap b2 = getImage(rowItem.getThumbnailImageId());
      Drawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(b2);
      holder.thumdnail.setBackground(drawable2);
    }

    return convertView;

}
```

Could you please tell me, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: hint: what happens when `rowItem.getThumbnailImageId() == null` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How ListView's recycling mechanism works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

Comment: you should implement else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to **njzk2** it seems your problem is we forgot to set the `visibility` to `VISIBLE` again in the if statement.

You need to specify what `geView` will do if there is no image :

```
if(rowItem.getThumbnailImageId() != null)
        {
            // here getImage() is converting byte array to bitmap

            Bitmap b2 = getImage(rowItem.getThumbnailImageId());
            Drawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(b2);
            holder.thumdnail.setBackground(drawable2);

            holder.thumdnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    else
    {
      //hide the image, or do anything you like when theres no image
      holder.thumdnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

The point is in the **else** code, so the `listview` know what to do when there is an image (your if statement) and if there's not (the else statement).

And try to make your holder class static :

```
private static class ViewHolder
```

Comment: I have tried doing `holder.thumdnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);` but it hides all the images after scrolling.

Comment: I dont know if this will work, try to set your holder class as "static" :  "private static class ViewHolder". I dont see any mistake in your code.

Comment: @pro_newbie: yes, of course, because in the other clause you don't set the visibility back.

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, that should be the problem

Comment: Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You should hide the ImageView if you don't have the thumbnailID:

```
if(rowItem.getThumbnailImageId() != null)
    {
        holder.thumdnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Bitmap b2 = getImage(rowItem.getThumbnailImageId());
        Drawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(b2);
        holder.thumdnail.setBackground(drawable2);
    }
else
{
     holder.thumdnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that. When I scroll down and back up, the listview only show titles and all the images have disappeared.

Comment: try calling LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); only once. Declare mInflater as a field of your adapter and initialize it on your constructor, i.e. on your public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<DataItems> items) method.

Comment: @pro_newbie: with that actual line `holder.thumdnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` ?

Comment: Nope, you are initializing the LayoutInflater every time the getView method is called. In all my adapters I only call this method once, in the contructor. I don't really know if this will solve your issue, but it surely is a better practice.